# Alive in the morning, dead at night. What am I?

Tags: riddle

> Each morning, I am given life by my master
> I work for my master all day long, and sometimes get heatstroke
> But, after a nap, I am back to work
> At night, before bed
> My master kills me
> Only to wake me again in the morn

What am I?

P.S.: This is my first original riddle, but it's not meant to be a rhyme. Please enjoy!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you are

> a mobile phone, or maybe a computer.

Explanations:

> Each morning it's turned on and used. If given a lot to do, it generates a lot of heat, and if its cooling systems aren't good enough (as is sometimes the case) it may have to shut down due to overheating. After shutting down for a bit, it's usable again. In the evening it's turned off, or at least put in some sort of standby mode, but it'll be needed again in the morning.

More generally, it seems like this could apply to

> any electrical or mechanical device used all day by a particular person and subject to occasional overheating. For instance, a taxi-driver's taxi.

Comment: It is supposed to be a computer, but I guess I wasn't specific enough. XD Thanks for the feedback, @Gareth

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but;

> Heart (the body part)

> Each morning, I am given life by my master

> Hearts return to your normal heartbeat and the "master" here is a person.

> I work for my master all day long, and sometimes get heatstroke

> Hearts always heartbeat, and the heart always suffers from damage because it did not cool itself. That is why you get heatstroke.

> But, after a nap, I am back to work

> If the person naps, Hearts will only have less heart rate than usual, but when they  wake up again, Hearts turn back to their average heart rate.

> At night, before bed
> My master kills me

> When people sleep, heart rate lowers

> Only to wake me again in the morn

> They are back to their original heartrate.

Comment: Close, and very creative! But not quite :P

Answer (score 0):

> Eyes

The only thing closes at night and while taking nap and wake up in the morning with the master, fun fact:- everybody has it. not everybody has

Comment: Close! But again, ever  that is turned on, used, and shut off at night has a master